# Выделение текущего пункта меню (PHP)

Tags: php, css

При изменении стиля, меняется всё меню целиком.

```
<div class="menu">
<?php 
$arr = array(
    'index.php'=>'Главная',
    'o_has.php'=>'О нас',
    'reg.php'=>'Регистрация',
    'kak_podkl.php'=> 'Как подключиться',
    ''=>'Карта мира',
    ''=>'Личный кабинет',
    ''=>'Список изменений',
    ''=>'Полезные статьи',
    ''=>'Форум'
);
foreach($arr as $key=>$value)
{
    if($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']==$key) echo "<li class=\"menu li\"><a href='$key' >$value</a></li>";
    else echo "<li id=\"li\"><a href='$key'>$value</a></li>";
}
?>
</div>
```

и срабатывает только последнее

```
else echo "<li id=\"li\"><a href='$key'>$value</a></li>";`
```

CSS:

```
.menu {
    display:table; 
    width:100%; 
    table-layout:fixed; 
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
.menu li /*текущая страница*/
{ /* градиентное меню */
    display:table-cell; 
    background:green; 
    padding:.5em; 
    text-align:center; 
    border:2px solid black; 
    background: green; /* Для старых браузров */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, green, black);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
(решетка)li /*текущая страница*/
{ /* градиентное меню */
    display:table-cell; 
    background:green; 
    padding:.5em; 
    text-align:center; 
    border:2px solid black; 
    background: green; /* Для старых браузров */
    background: linear-gradient(to top, black, black);
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #333;
}
```

Помогите доработать код чтобы выделялся только текущий пункт меню.

Comment: У вас тут много ошибок:
   1. Правило ".menu li" не применится ни к чему, т.к. у вас не элементов li внутри элемента с классом menu.... Подозреваю, что класс menu должен быть у тега ul;   2 У вас получается более одного элемента с id="li" это грубая ошибка. id должен быть уникальным в пределах страницы.

Answer (score 1):

Возможно $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] возвращает '/index.php'. т.е. со слешем. скорее всего в этом дело. Посмотрите что находится в $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].

И еще так делать в массиве нехорошо:

```
''=>'Карта мира',
''=>'Личный кабинет',
''=>'Список изменений',
''=>'Полезные статьи',
''=>'Форум'
```

лучше без ключей пишите

```
'Карта мира',
'Личный кабинет',
'Список изменений',
'Полезные статьи',
'Форум'
```